# use aync to set variable value in constructor

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, asynchronous

i have problem with async functions in constructor.

I have a variable whose content must be read in a json file using an http call,

```
{
"serverIP":"host/api"
}
```

it contains the url to the api and its value must then be used by other variables

```
urlserveur!:string
url1!:string
url2!:string

 public  getJSON(): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get("assets/serveur.json")
 }

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
  this.urlserveur = data.serverIP
 });
 
 this.url1= this.urlserveur + 'list/'
 this.url1= this.urlserveur + 'insert'
}
```

the problem is that the assignment of the url1 and url2 variables in the constructor is done before the query that initializes the urlserver variable

note that I read the url by http call because I want to be able to modify the json file in the assets folder after deployment. I don't want the value to be permanently set at compile time
thank you

Comment: Put the assignments of `url1` inside the `subscribe` callback?

Comment: I'd normally suggest a static `async` function that returns a promise for a fully-formed instance, but I don't know how/whether Angular handles dependency injection in static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just move them inside your subscribe block

```
urlserveur!:string
url1!:string
url2!:string

 public  getJSON(): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get("assets/serveur.json")
 }

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
  this.urlserveur = data.serverIP;
  this.url1= this.urlserveur + 'list/'
  this.url1= this.urlserveur + 'insert'
 });

}
```